# Flask always getting reportMissingImports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm always getting `reportMissingImports` regardless if the package installed or not.

app.py:

[image]

pip freeze output (in our virtualenv)

```
aniso8601==8.1.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-JWT==0.3.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
PyJWT==1.4.2
pytz==2020.5
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.22
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Flask --version output in my virtual env:

```
Python 3.9.1
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```

My file structure:

```
/code
 /app.y
 /create_table.py
 /item.py
 /user.py
 /securiy.py
/venv
```

> Note: this is happening for some of the packages and not all of them

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in Settings.json:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [

    //The relative or absolute path of modules
    "./modules",
    "/the absolute path to flask_jwt/",　
    ...　　
],
```

Then save the settings and reload the window to make it effective.

Comment: Actually, for packages installed, you just need the path to the *site-packages* folder, so it solves all missing imports, not just flask_jwt.

Comment: You're right, but sometimes this error will only be caused by one specific module, add it with absolute path is clear to understand.